# Remove symbols from character data column

Tags: r, regex, symbols

Is it possible to remove symbols from a character column, in rmarkdown?

```
c("Between ��20,000-��29,999 --", "Between �20,000-�29,999 --")
```

I would like to replace � with £ (or empty string "").
I would leave it but some responses have 1 and others 2, due to this it is not allowing me to group correctly.

I have tried

```
stri_replace_all_regex(f$`What is the number that best describes your TOTAL household income BEFORE TAX?`, c("�")," ")
```

but no success.

Comment: I did not think very carefully on this, but this is my quick solution: `gsub("(£)\\1+", "\\1", gsub("�", "£", x))`? where `x` is your variable/column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
vec <- c("Between ��20,000-��29,999 --", "Between �20,000-�29,999 --")
gsub("�+", "£", vec)
# [1] "Between £20,000-£29,999 --" "Between £20,000-£29,999 --"
```

The `+` means "one or more" of consecutive matches.

If you must have it with `stringr`, then it's just a different order of arguments:

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(vec, "�+", "£")
# [1] "Between £20,000-£29,999 --" "Between £20,000-£29,999 --"
```

Comment: Thank you so much the 1st option you gave worked great.